# Callback vs Promise in 2018

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

What is nowadays standard for making async functions?

I am not trying to ask here option based question, rather that asking what is used more in 2018 and what is better for future scalability.

Style #1:

```
const client = new SteamUser();
    exports.setup = callback => {
        client.on('webSession', async (sessionID, cookies) => {
            offers.setup(client, cookies, callback);
        });

        client.on('error', err => {
           callback(error)
        });
    };
```

Style #2:

```
const client = new SteamUser();
    exports.setup = async () => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            client.on('webSession', async (sessionID, cookies) => {
                resolve(await offers.setup(client, cookies));
            });

            client.on('error', err => {
               reject(error)
            });
         });
        };
```

Both called in another file by:

```
    try{
await module.setup();
} catch(err){
console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Style #3: async/await

Comment: How? When u use async await u need also promises right?

Comment: You're asking about style. async/await hides the promises.

Comment: The "standard" would be to use `util.promisify` to turn all the callback accepting functions into promises. And then use async/await. ;)

Comment: Yes I want to use await/async but I have no idea how to compose my example into it

Comment: Style #4 observables

Comment: That will depend on how `client.on()` is coded.

Comment: If you can't use root-level async/await, use an Async IIFE: `(async () => {/** Your code goes here**/})();`

Comment: @DenysSéguret `async/await` has further useful features, like automatically rejecting when an error is thrown. Baterka this question is definitely opinion based, so it's best to search and read the many useful resources already available on the topic. Pick the right tool for the job, not the "trendiest".

Comment: style 2 you're mixing async/await with regular promises

Comment: `what is better for future scalability` - that would be based on opinion

Comment: Its highly possible... I edited my question to give better understanding what system I need

Comment: @Boaz couldn't agree more about the right tool for the job

Comment: You can't await on something that doesn't return a promise - so your `Both called in another file by` makes absolutely no sense

Comment: @Baterka Opinion based is asking *is X better than Y?* This kind of questions is discouraged, since they depends too much on the personal preference and idiosyncrasies of the person answering.

Comment: @JaromandaX youre right sorry

Comment: for instance, my *opinion* is that `async`/`await` isn't always better than old school promises - it's overused because it's "new" or because asynchrony scares some programmers, so better to have code that *looks* more synchronous

Answer (score 5):

Promises help you to have a more readable and maintenable code. Working with promises involve less nesting compared to callbacks.

The code below use callback:

```
someMethod = (arg) => {
    getSomething1(arg, res1 => {
        getSomething2(res1, res2 => {
            getSomething3(res2, res3 => {
                /* Do something here */
            });
        });
    })
}
```

There's too many nesting in the code above: a callback inside a callback inside a callback ... (callback hell). More you have callbacks, more it's difficult to read.

By using Promise, it becomes:

```
var someMethod = (arg) => {
    getSomething1(arg).then(res1 => {
        return getSomething2(res1);
    }).then(res2 => {
        return getSomething3(res2);
    }).then(res3 => {
       /* Do something here */
    });
}
```

And it's now more readable since promise allows you to chain things vertically.

It can be further enhanced by using async await:

```
someMethod() = async (arg) => {
    var res1 = await getSomething1(arg);
    var res2 = await getSomething2(res1);
    var res3 = await getSomething3(res2); 
    /* Do something here */
}
```

And it's now looks like a synchronous code: easy to read and maintain.

Answer (score -1):

I think we should go definitly towards a try/catch approach. The [Pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_create) docs have a nice overview how their functions are made in the three possible different ways.

Callbacks

```
db.allDocs({
  include_docs: true,
  attachments: true
}, function(err, response) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  // handle result
});
```

Promise

```
db.allDocs({
  include_docs: true,
  attachments: true
}).then(function (result) {
  // handle result
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Async try/catch

```
try {
  var result = await db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    attachments: true
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```